# CSS background image style via ID selector not applying

Tags: html, css

I am facing a simple problem that is taking up a lot of my time.

I have a simple CSS that defines an image as background:

```
#header-content{
     background-image: url("../images/header-img.png");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position-x: center;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
}
```

And the div in a HTML page that has this ID:

```
<!-- HEADER -->
<div id="header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-12">
                 <div id="header-content">

                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
<!-- HEADER -->
```

Very simple. But the image is not shown. What could be the problem?

P.S.: The image directory is correct.

Comment: Your problem could be that the `#header-content` div doesn't have any size. Try adding: `height: 100px; width: 200px`

Comment: Good, worked! But now the image is not 100% width. There is a margin in both sides.

Comment: Do some more research on CSS

Comment: @Developer1903 please have a look at my answer - defining the width is not necessary, since the default width *is* 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem could be that the #header-content div doesn't have any size. Try adding: `height: 100px; width: 200px`

```css
#header-content{
 background-image: url("http://unsplash.com/photos/1-ISIwuBMiw/download");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position-x: center;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 100px;
 width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!-- HEADER -->
<div id="header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-12">
                 <div id="header-content">

                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
<!-- HEADER -->
```

Comment: why `width: 200px` ?

Comment: @Johannes - no reason, arbitrary number to make the example work

Comment: it's 100% by default, there is no need to define a width

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to set `width` ( the default for DOVs is 100%), but if you don't have any content in that DIV, you have to set a `height` value for that DIV  to see a background (if not, it's 0px high = not visible).

Answer (score 0):

Set `height` and `width` to your `#header-content`.

Answer (score 0):

Also, when setting the height, try a different measuring unit than percentage(%) because percentage might not work correctly sometimes and it'll make it not to show as well. You can use px or vh.

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't defined `width` and `height` in your css code.
For example, add these `width: 400px; height: 400px;` to the first of `#header-content {}`, and it works. you can also do it for body or even HTML tag without using `width` and `height` properties.